# How to quickly toggle HDR mode on D7200?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings, hdr, nikon-d7200

I know how to turn on/off HDR function on D7200 from menu, but I wonder if there is a quicker way to toggle this function.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign this function to a `Fn`+`dial` combination.

**Custom Settings menu → F Controls → Assign Fn Button → Press + command dials → choose HDR**.

Then you can switch to the HDR modes with `Fn` + `Main Dial`.